# React hook with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to use code from material ui and am getting this error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I am unsure what is causing the issue if I am not using a class (since i know that react hooks cannot be used inside a class). Im wondering if this has something to do with the ReactDOM?

This is the only code I am using:

=======index.js=======

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './Pages/HomePage.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

=======HomePage.js=======

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AB from '../Components/AppBar';

export default function HP() {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

  if (buttonClicked === false ) 
      return (
          <Button color="info" onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)}>Get Started</Button>
      )
  if (buttonClicked) return (<AB/>)
};
```

=======AppBar.js=======

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'block',
    },
  },
  search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: 120,
      '&:focus': {
        width: 200,
      },
    },
  },
}));

export default function SearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
            Material-UI
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Check point 1 and 3 in your project

Comment: I have checked for both and it seems fine. No duplicates or version mismatches. They are both 16.10.2

Comment: Please paste the actual error log.. full log from console

Comment: its working good https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-joliot-pvukb?fontsize=14 .

Comment: I just added it to the description :)

Comment: Okay, I will have to figure out why on my computer then because youre right, it did work in codesandbox

Comment: Are you using react app inside another react app? `You might have more than one copy of React in the same app` don't perform child react app use as separate folder

Comment: No, I just checked that. I thank you for trying to assist me though. I might recreate the project and see if that fixes anything

Comment: Code wise good .Check the 3rd point or do with new folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useStyles` or `makeStyles` itself is a hook provided by material-ui it should be inside the functional component.

```
import React from 'react'
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase'
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search'

export default function SearchAppBar() {
    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        edge="start"
                        className={classes.menuButton}
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer">
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
                        Material-UI
                    </Typography>
                    <div className={classes.search}>
                        <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                            <SearchIcon />
                        </div>
                        <InputBase
                            placeholder="Search…"
                            classes={{
                                root: classes.inputRoot,
                                input: classes.inputInput
                            }}
                            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        display: 'none',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'block'
        }
    },
    search: {
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25)
        },
        marginLeft: 0,
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            width: 'auto'
        }
    },
    searchIcon: {
        width: theme.spacing(7),
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        pointerEvents: 'none',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    inputRoot: {
        color: 'inherit'
    },
    inputInput: {
        padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
        width: '100%',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: 120,
            '&:focus': {
                width: 200
            }
        }
    }
}))
```